# cake php insert query in loop

Tags: php, cakephp

Hello Every one i have a function in controller which is checkout where i am submitting a form. 
But i want to run insert query in a loop on bellow $this->Session->read('Cart') value is 3 but my code insert one record in table if i alert something inside loop it alerts 3 time how can i run insert query 3 time please any one help me.
Thanks in advance.

---

```
public function checkout() {
        $this->loadModel("Checkout");
        Configure::read();
        $aorderno = $this->Checkout->find('all', array('order' => array('Checkout.id' => 'DESC'),'limit' => 1));    
        $this->set('aorderno',$aorderno);
           foreach($aorderno as $order)
           {
           $myorderno=$order['Checkout']['orderno']+1;
           }
        $firstname = $this->request->data['checkout']['firstname'];
        $this->set('firstname',$firstname);
        $lastname = $this->request->data['checkout']['lastname'];
        $this->set('lastname',$lastname);
if(count($this->Session->read('Cart'))>0)
             {
                    foreach($this->Session->read('Cart') as $value)
                    {
                    $sku=$value['Product']['sku'];
                    $this->Checkout->save(array('orderno' => $myorderno,'firstname' => $firstname,'lastname' => $lastname'sku' => $sku));
                    }
             }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I supposed in your $this->Checkout->saveQuery function.

You are using something like $this->save();

Before $this->save(), call $this->create();

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use saveMany

```
    foreach(.......){
        $arr[]= array('orderno' => $myorderno,'firstname' => $firstname,'lastname' => $lastname'sku' => $sku);
    }

   $this->Checkout->saveMany($arr, array('deep' => true));
```